Iptables rules to allow outgoing DNS lookups, only from my DNS ip
Well, i'm getting mad whith this :D
This is the only configuration which allow me to browse.
My Iptables rules:
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -f -j DROP

My dns server:
cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.254
dig MYIP

;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1) (UDP)
I tried this way:
#1
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -p udp  -j ACCEPT

#2
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#3
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp5s0 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp5s0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

#4
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp5s0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i enp5s0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT


Well, you have been using -s dns_server in OUTPUT, so... (and -s lan_subnet in INPUT...)

"Well, you have been using -s dns_server in OUTPUT, so... (and -s lan_subnet in INPUT...)" Can you please tell me the correct rules?
